Using `MakeOuterQuote` in the title
I use both the babel and the csquotes package when I write in german. I use \MakeOuterQuote{"}, so that I only have to type " to start and end a quote, and csquotes takes care of placing the correct character (lowered at the beginning, like a double comma, and above at the end). Today I realized that this does not work in titles, though. Instead I have to use the more cumbersome \enquote{...}.
Is there any way to make it work as in the normal text?

Here is a minimal working example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\title{Whatever \enquote{you} do}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}

Here is a minimal non-working example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\title{Whatever "you" do}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

At this point, the "quotes" work as intended.
\end{document}

Output next to each other:


move the title definition behind \begin{document}. And better disable babels shorthands, you are breaking them anyway \usepackage[ngerman,shorthands=off]{babel}. Personally I wouldn't use " for quotes, imho it is too fragile. I have shortcuts in my editor that surrounds text with „“ or \enquote.
